# matrix 10 times heavier than expected in cpp

Tags: c++

I wrote this little code that creates a matrix. the size of the matrix is 500 x 100 000. The elements of the matrix are vectors of doubles of size 10.
I expect the size of memory to stock this object should be something close to :  500 x 100 000 x 10 octets = 500 MB.
However when I compile it with g++, the object takes 5GB.
Do you know why the object is so heavy?

Here is the code :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<vector<vector<double>>> truc;
    truc.resize(500);
    for (int i =0; i<500; i++) {
        truc[i].resize(100000);
        for (int j=0; j<100000; j++) {
            truc[i][j].resize(10);
        }
    }
```

and I compile it with the command :

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 main.cpp -o main
```

Comment: A double takes more than 1 octet space.

Comment: I guess if you have just 500 x 100 000 doubles it would be the case of your expectation. But you are forgetting about vectors and all the pointers. Those use memory too.

Comment: On most processor, a double weights 8 bytes. `500 x 100 000 x 10 x 8 ~ 4GB`. You can get a type size with `std::cout << "sizeof(double) = " << sizeof(double) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the actual `double`s, you require `500*100000*10*sizeof(double)` bytes.  `sizeof(double)` is usually 8 bytes, which brings you to 4,000,000,000 bytes.

In addition, the `std::vector`s themselves require some space for their internal fields which manage the data: e.g. on 64-Bit Linux with `gcc`, `sizeof(std::vector<double>)` is 24.  You create a total of (1+500+500*100000) `std::vector` objects, which by itself comes to 1,200,012,024 bytes.

You may want to think about using a sparse data structure, which explicitly stores only non-zero entries, if that is feasible for the kind of data you deal with.  [The Eigen matrix library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) comes to my mind as a possible candidate.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will take a look at this library. I actually simplified a little bit my code to be clearer. In my real code, I create vector of maps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the standard says about the number of bytes used to store a `double` (emphasis mine):

> § 3.9.1
>
> There are three floating point types: float, double, and long double. The type double provides at least
>   as much precision as float, and the type long double provides at least as much precision as double.
>   The set of values of the type float is a subset of the set of values of the type double; the set of values
>   of the type double is a subset of the set of values of the type long double. **The value representation of
>   floating-point types is implementation-defined.** Integral and floating types are collectively called arithmetic
>   types. Specializations of the standard template std::numeric_limits (18.3) shall specify the maximum
>   and minimum values of each arithmetic type for an implementation.

Therefore, the amount of space required is entirely down the the implementation of your compiler.

As mentioned in the comments, `sizeof(double)` will reveal how many bytes are required to store a double on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

In memory a double is 8 byte = 8 oct.

The memory used by a vector is:

```
// size of vector + size of type * n.elements
sizeof(std::vector<double>) + (sizeof(double) * n_elem);
```

so, a **vector< double > of 10 elements** has the size of: 24 + (8 * 10) = **104 byte/oct**;

But you have a vector of vector of that type, so:

```
24 + [24 + (24 + 8*10) * 100 000] * 500 ~ 5Go.
```

Answer (score 0):

A `double` is not an octet.    An octet is a set of 8 bits, and is equivalent to a single `char` (with most implementations).    The size of a `double` is implementation dependent, but typically has a size of 8 BYTES, which is equivalent to 8 octets.

So multiply your expected memory usage by `8` to get a lower bound on memory usage.   Bear in mind that every vector will use additional memory (e.g. to keep track of the set of `double`s they manage) - and your vector `truc` contains `500*100000 = 50,000,000` of them.   Your calculation is not taking those into account at all.

Comment: Thank you ! I was aware of the difference between bits and octets; but it's my first time noticing the difference between byte and bit.